# Protect against inadvertent command entry

Tags: security, shell

I have a couple boxes in production and then some in a test environment.  Anyone have any clever ways to protect against typing in inadvertent commands into boxes? i.e. I want to put a confirmation when you try to shutdown/reboot the production boxes in case one makes a mistake and types it into the wrong shell window.

Linux

Comment: Don't run as root on the production servers? ;)

Comment: We don't run as root but all have sudo access, so 'sudo shutdown -r now' is natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like [molly-guard](http://packages.debian.org/sid/molly-guard) might do what you want.

Comment: This is actually perfect and exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.